# Unable to do column formatting (in excel) on column containing dates, after converting from .csv to .xlsx using to_excel using python pandas

Tags: python

[Date column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hxn7.jpg)

```py
import pandas as pd

df_new=pd.read_csv('date.csv')
df_new.to_excel('date.xlsx',index=False,header=True)
```

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

@shivs - once you get the dataframe, you need to convert the date column to datetime and then insert into excel... this will covert it to the standard datetime format in excel. What you are doing will just consider this as a string and add it to excel. So, add the additional line as below...

```
import pandas as pd 
df_new=pd.read_csv('date.csv') 
df_new['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_new['date'])
df_new.to_excel('date.xlsx',index=False,header=True)
```

**Excel output**

[image]

Comment: thankyou for the clear solution, that helps a lot.